# Error parsing file arguments error on jar with entry point creation

Tags: java, jar

I've create simple java project with single class - `Main` with main method printing `Hello`.

```java
package com.foo;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Code was compiled to `bin` directory. I'm trying to create jar using command

```
jar -cfe project.jar com.foo.Main -C bin\
```

with no results, always returning `Error parsing file arguments` error.
I also tried many different variations, like

```
jar --create --file project.jar --main-class com.foo.Main -C bin
```

but none of it worked. I'm using Java 16

Answer (score 3):

Try running this. It should create the 'project.jar'

```
jar --create --file project.jar --main-class com.foo.Main -C bin .
```

-C flag Temporarily changes directories (cd dir) during execution of the jar command while processing the following inputfiles argument.

This command changes to bin directory and adds to project.jar all files within the bin directory (without creating a bin directory in the jar file).

For more information check the -C part in the OPTIONS section :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jar.html#options

Comment: I guess the difference between what OP tried and what you suggest, is the `.` at the end? Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: @sanastasiadis The . at the end of the -C commands is to go back to the original directory

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: the . at the end tells which files to select: if you put a file or a list of files present in the subfolder, it will include those files, if you put . it will take all of the files in the folder

Answer (score 0):

You need both a "=" after main-class and a "." at the end to selct al lthe files

jar --create --file project.jar --main-class=com.foo.Main -C bin .

or

jar cfe project.jar com.foo.Main -C bin .